# Rotate video in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, video, camera

I am new to iOS.

I have an app for record video and play it in iPad.

Now I have to open camera in view. So I used avcapturesession for that.

Now by my coding I can record and play video but the video recorded is in rotated mode.

I use LandscapeRight for recording.

Here is my coding:

```
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
                    captureVideoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;

                    captureVideoPreviewLayer.orientation=AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight;
                    captureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = vwvideo.bounds;

                    [vwvideo.layer addSublayer:captureVideoPreviewLayer];

                    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

                    NSError *error = nil;
                    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];
                    if (!input) {
                        // Handle the error appropriately.
                        NSLog(@"ERROR: trying to open camera: %@", error);
                    }

                    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

                    AVCaptureMovieFileOutput *movieFileOutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init];

                    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

                    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
                    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.SS"];
                    NSDate *now = [[[NSDate alloc] init] autorelease];
                    theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:now];

                    NSString *tempPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.mp4",documentsDirectory,theDate];
                    [tempPath retain];
                    NSLog(@"Path::%@",tempPath);

                    NSURL *outputURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:tempPath];
                                        [session addInput:input];
                    [session addOutput:movieFileOutput];
                    [session commitConfiguration];
                    [session startRunning];

                    [movieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:outputURL recordingDelegate:self];
```

Answer (score 6):

http://www.raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-ios/videoplayrecord

If you go thorough the code of the sample project, given in that tutorial its easy to fix the rotated video to the correct orientation by this following snippet.(RecordVideo.m file)

```
        //FIXING ORIENTATION//
    AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *FirstlayerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:firstTrack];
    AVAssetTrack *FirstAssetTrack = [[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
    UIImageOrientation FirstAssetOrientation_  = UIImageOrientationUp;
    BOOL  isFirstAssetPortrait_  = NO;
    CGAffineTransform firstTransform = FirstAssetTrack.preferredTransform;
    if(firstTransform.a == 0 && firstTransform.b == 1.0 && firstTransform.c == -1.0 && firstTransform.d == 0)  {FirstAssetOrientation_= UIImageOrientationRight; isFirstAssetPortrait_ = YES;}
    if(firstTransform.a == 0 && firstTransform.b == -1.0 && firstTransform.c == 1.0 && firstTransform.d == 0)  {FirstAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationLeft; isFirstAssetPortrait_ = YES;}
    if(firstTransform.a == 1.0 && firstTransform.b == 0 && firstTransform.c == 0 && firstTransform.d == 1.0)   {FirstAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationUp;}
    if(firstTransform.a == -1.0 && firstTransform.b == 0 && firstTransform.c == 0 && firstTransform.d == -1.0) {FirstAssetOrientation_ = UIImageOrientationDown;}
    CGFloat FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio = 1.0;
    if(isFirstAssetPortrait_){
        FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio = 1.0;
        CGAffineTransform FirstAssetScaleFactor = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio,FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio);
        [FirstlayerInstruction setTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(FirstAssetTrack.preferredTransform, FirstAssetScaleFactor) atTime:kCMTimeZero];
    }else{
        CGAffineTransform FirstAssetScaleFactor = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio,FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio);
        [FirstlayerInstruction setTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformConcat(FirstAssetTrack.preferredTransform, FirstAssetScaleFactor),CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 160)) atTime:kCMTimeZero];
    }

    [FirstlayerInstruction setOpacity:0.0 atTime:videoAsset.duration];

    AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *SecondlayerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:AudioTrack];


    MainInstruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:FirstlayerInstruction,nil];;

    AVMutableVideoComposition *MainCompositionInst = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
    MainCompositionInst.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:MainInstruction];
    MainCompositionInst.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);
    MainCompositionInst.renderSize = CGSizeMake(360.0, 480.0);

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
    NSString *myPathDocs =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"orientationFixedVideo-%d.mov",arc4random() % 1000]];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPathDocs];

    AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality];
    exporter.outputURL=url;
    exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
    exporter.videoComposition = MainCompositionInst;
    exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
    [exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^
     {
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             [self exportDidFinish:exporter];
         });
     }];
```